# Website has horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

i am currently making a website but i have a horizontal scroll bar... here is the CSS for the body/html

```
body,html {
    min-width:600px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Calibri;
}
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/charliejsford/8DSBY/

how can i get rid of the horizontal scrollbar even when the screen size is changed?

Comment: Add `overflow:hidden;` ?

Answer (score 7):

You should remove the width property from your footer css.

Overflow will mask the problem but doesn't address the root issue with the layout.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following in your CSS body tag:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

That will remove your scrollbar.

Comment: aha excellent - thank you. how can i make it so the header divs dont overlap each other and they still look ok on a smaller screen?

Comment: As @middleinitial mentioned, there are some issues with your css as a whole. If you're going to build something that is mobile friendly, either have 2 different css files and call them based on the browser information or build your page for mobile and then allow it to expand to larger sizes. If you're comfortable with using (or trying to use) libraries, there are some good css bootstraps out there to get you going in that direction.

Comment: Adding this to the footer element fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
width:auto; can solve your doubt?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing width:100% from your CSS